# Financial Services Cloud Unit Testing - Inserting AccountContactRelation Fails

Tags: apex, person-accounts, accountcontactrelation, financial-services-cloud, households

I am trying to create a unit test in Financial Services Cloud that tests operations on Household Roles.  The org uses Person Accounts. Whenever I try and insert an AccountContactRelation with the Person Account set as primary (FinServ__Primary__c = true), the insertion fails with the following error:

> System.DmlException: Insert failed. First exception on row 0; first error: FIELD_CUSTOM_VALIDATION_EXCEPTION, Can't choose a business as a primary group or primary member.: []

Here is my setup method.  It creates an account with RecordType of 'Client Household'.  Then it creates a Person Account.  Finally, I attempt to relate the two accounts by inserting a record into AccountContactRelation.

```
@testSetup static void setup() 
{
    RecordType householdRecordType =  [SELECT Id FROM RecordType WHERE (Name = 'Household') AND (SObjectType = 'Account')];
    Account a = new Account(
        Name = 'Test Household',
        RecordType = householdRecordType
    );
    insert a;

    RecordType personAccountRecordType = [SELECT Id FROM RecordType WHERE (Name = 'Person Account') AND (SObjectType = 'Account')];
    Account pa = new Account(
        FirstName = 'Test',
        LastName = 'Person Account',
        RecordType = personAccountRecordType,
        FinServ__IndividualType__c = 'Individual'
    );
    insert pa;

    // Need to get the PersonContactId for the Person Account
    pa = [SELECT PersonContactId FROM Account WHERE Id = :pa.Id];

    AccountContactRelation acr = new AccountContactRelation(
        AccountId = a.Id,
        ContactId = pa.PersonContactId,
        IsActive = true,
        FinServ__PrimaryGroup__c = true,
        FinServ__Primary__c = true,
        Roles = 'Client',
        FinServ__Rollups__c = 'Tasks;Events;Financial Accounts'
    );
    insert acr;
}
```

Comment: That is caused by either a validation rule or an Apex trigger `addError()`.  Have you checked your validation rules and unmanaged Apex?

Comment: This appears to be coming from Salesforce's FSC managed package, but I can't narrow down where.

Comment: You'll probably need to open a case with Salesforce.

Comment: Okay, it turns out that querying the RecordType object is not the way to do this.  I should have used the Schema.SObjectType.Account.getRecordTypeInfosByName() method instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The proper way to get the RecordTypeId is to use the Schema.SObjectType.Account.getRecordTypeInfosByName() method, not by querying the RecordType object.

```
Id householdRecordTypeId = Schema.SObjectType.Account.getRecordTypeInfosByName().get('Household').getRecordTypeId();
Id personRecordTypeId = Schema.SObjectType.Account.getRecordTypeInfosByName().get('Person Account').getRecordTypeId();
```